# How to convert a string into a date-time object

Tags: r, data-manipulation, lubridate

The data is character  and I want it to be date-time. I have the cheat sheet with me but there isn't any format that I can use that satisfies the weird date format. Any suggestions?

```
x <- 'Fri Dec 11 12:10:51 PST 2020'
```

Comment: see the individual formats in `?strptime` and build a string that fits your complete format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package

```
> library(anytime)
> anytime("Fri Dec 11 12:10:51 PST 2020")
[1] "2020-12-11 12:10:51 CST"
> 
> class(anytime("Fri Dec 11 12:10:51 PST 2020"))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
>
```

It has three key advantages:

- it can guess the format (as here)
- it converts all sorts of input format (incl character, factor, ...)
- it is pretty fast (as the parser is C++ from Boost)

It is pretty standard for most methods to ignore the timezone attribute. So the PST became my local time, *i.e.* Central.

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could do :

```
x <- 'Fri Dec 11 12:10:51 PST 2020'
as.POSIXct(x, format = '%a %b %d %T PST %Y')
```

See `?strptime` for detailed format specifications.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't know how to specify the 'Fri' 'Dec' and other non-conventional date entries.